# How to display review app url in github pull request

Tags: github, github-api

It is possible for heroku to include review app link in pull request: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#viewing-review-apps
Is it possible to display such link when I have my own review apps deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Once it's deployed (and optionally before that a passed CI, if it's configured in the Heroku Review App settings) the environment URL will be added to the corresponding Pull Request in the timeline section of the PR. Once you click on `View deployment` the URL will be opened.

[image: GitHub Pull Request timeline]